# How to use PHP class extends?

Tags: php, class

***QUESTION :***

I Cannot figure how to use classes extends in PHP... Even reading php.net website and some examples, there is something I cannot understand or missing !

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Api.php

```
class Api
{

    public static $action = '';


#    public function __construct()
#    {
#    }

    public function actionCaller ($action,$args=NULL)
    {
        return self::$action_($args);
    }
}
```

ApiForum.php

```
class ApiForum extends Api
{

    #private static $forum;

    public function __construct()
    {
        #self::$forum = new Api();
    }

    private function getPost ($args)
    {
        echo 'executed.';
        #return "get forum post $args";
    }

}
```

test.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);


require_once('config.php');
require_once('classes/_Autoload_.php');


echo Api::actionCaller('forum')->getPost();
```

The result :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPost() on a non-object in /var/www/html/api.example.com/test.php on line 10
```

Please be clement with me ;)

CL

***ANSWER:***

Okay it's working now ! Thanks to all... There was more than one problem, here is the result :

**Api.php**

```
class Api
{

#    public function __construct()
#    {
#    }


    public function actionCaller ($action,$args=NULL)
    {
        return self::$action($args);
    }

    public function forum ()
    {
        return new ApiForum();
    }


}
```

**ApiForum.php**

```
class ApiForum extends Api
{

#    public function __construct()
#    {
#    }



    public static function getPost ($args)
    {
        echo 'executed.';
    }

}
```

**test.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);


require_once('config.php');
require_once('classes/_Autoload_.php');


echo Api::actionCaller('forum')->getPost('test');
```

I feel I need some more readings about classes and objects scopes ... :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry ;
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPost() on a non-object in /var/www/html/api.example.com/test.php on line 10

Comment: I want to call there methods from my index.php :
Api::actionCaller('forum')->getPost();

Comment: That has nothing to do with class extensions.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I'm just looking at the bad place... It's my first API and I would like to have "separate" kind of actions, in fact, I must probably call them "contexts of actions". Do you have some simple readings or a track to follow to do this ?

Comment: @Coldlight Can we see your test.php file? And the whole of it, so we can tell which one is line 10!

Comment: @AdiBradfield Sure, but there is pretty much only these test call ;)
I'll edit my question !

Comment: Normally a "Call on non-object" error is due to a previous function failing and providing a "false" return to indicate an error, and that you haven't put in the right checks in to see if that is the case. Well that is usually the source of those errors when I do a lot of database work, which considering this is a forum, seems likely!

Comment: That's because your "getPost" method is private instead of static :')

Comment: To be honest, it's (re)start from scratch... I have something working but very crap and not oriented object... I have a lot of old stuff in procedural and now I have more time to me, I would like to refactory some big pieces ;)

Comment: Ahh okay fair enough! But it is still worth looking at my answer, and working out the difference bewtween the different scopes of method when working with OOP programming! What seems very trivial to people who have worked with it a while now, I can still remember it tripping me up when I first started moving over to OOP!

Comment: take note `public`, `private`, `static` keywords. Understand them before using.

Comment: Yes, it's working ! There was many problems... I wanted to post/answer my question but my poor reputation (^^) do that I cannot answer my own question before 8 hours delays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch your "getPost" method declaration for this:

```
static function getPost($args){
```

A private method means only that class can execute that method. A static method means that it can be called without an object being instantiated, like what you're trying to do with the double colon eg. `class::method(args)`.

Just for completeness sake, a public function is the middle ground. An object has to be instantiated for you to call it (via `$object->method(args)`), but it is available to any file that has imported that class

### EDIT

Just a side note: I'd also like to add that for a method to be used as a static method, it still needs to be "included"! I apologise for the use of the word "imported", I've been playing around in a lot of other languages recently!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just edited the post to include the working code... I will do some readings about public/private scopes and try to understand a little bit more complicated examples this saturday :)

Comment: Good! It's really not that complicated at all, it's just a little "gotcha" if you're trying to teach yourself (like I did!)